# I am not able to find master page when i am trying to create one

Tags: asp.net

This is the screenshot [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Cmx.png)

I am trying to add a master page in my asp.net web app . But after i choose add new item i am not able to find master page to create one.Thanks in advance

Comment: that' really vague, you should provide more information.

Comment: I am trying to add a master page to my application. .master is missing .

Comment: From the screenshot, you are creating a MVC View, not Webform Master page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using VS2015 then

```
Step 1: Right Click on Project
step 2 : Add  
Step 3 : New Item 
Step 4 : web 
and select
Step 5 : web form master page
```

Now you can see your new master page with .master extension

see screenshot: [image: iFour Technolab]

Answer (score 0):

You will right click on the project file instead of solution file in solution explorer window.

Comment: Ya i have clicked on the project file itself

Comment: when  i created as new website i got the option but when i created as a web application i did not.what is the difference